# What is most common solution to resolve data mapper for a domain object

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, datamapper, abstraction

G'day,
I've tried to do a search on a subject but couldn't find anything, at least yet.

I have a 3 domain objects that implement interface IEntity. I'd like to build a generic data mapper layer to do Create, Update, Delete operations on IEntity. Problem is that each concrete entity is saved in its own table so it seems I need to have 3 concrete mappers to deal with that.
However client doesn't know anything about concrete objects - it only knows about IEntity abstration. And obviously I don't want concrete objects to know anything about mappers.

So it seems that there should be a way for client to get mapper of the right type. Would service locator pattern be used in cases like that?

Something like:

```
public IEntityDataMapper GetMapper(IEntity entity)
```

Some other ways to accomplish this goal? Is it by any chance the sign of my domain model being somewhat faulty in the first place?

**Example of what I'm trying to accomplish:**
(client code)

```
IEntityMapper mapper; 
IEntity abstractEntity; 

mapper.Update(abstractEntity);
```

Logic behind Update for every entity may be very different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are looking for but it sounds like a case for Automapper.

http://automapper.codeplex.com/

p.s.  I assume you are using .Net...  but I guess you never specified...

Comment: I've edited my post - added an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear on what you want to do, either -> but are you familiar with the concept of ORMs, for example NHibernate, are you trying to map those entites to a relational database?
You can have abstractions like those with simple NHibernate session:

```
IEntity someEntity = new Customer("John", "Doe");
session.Save(someEntity);
```

provided that you map the entity to the database...